# Angular 6/7/8 Nested Child Routes using 'loadChildren()', not displaying

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-router, angular-module

I am learning angular and have started my chapter on routing, I would like my project that I am wokring along side my learning to have individual modules and routes that handle them.

Below is my code to handle routing.

***app-routing.module.ts***

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import {PatientsDataComponent} from './main-page/main/patients/patients-data/patients-data.component';
import {RightPanelComponent} from './main-page/main/patients/right-panel/right-panel.component';


const routes: Routes = [{
  path: 'patients',
  component: PatientsDataComponent,
  children: [{
    path: '',
    component: RightPanelComponent,
    loadChildren: () => import('./main-page/main/patients/right-panel/right-panel.module').then(m => m.RightPanelModule),
    data: { preload: true }
  }]
  }];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

And my other routing module looks like this

***right-panel-routing.module.ts***

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import {EditDetailsComponent} from './edit-details/edit-details.component';
import {AppGuard} from '../../../../app.guard';
import {RightPanelComponent} from './right-panel.component';

const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: RightPanelComponent,
  children: [{
    path: 'editDetails/:id',
    component: EditDetailsComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }]
}];


@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class RightPanelRoutingModule {

}
```

What I am trying to do is to show the ***edit-details.component*** on click of a dynamic list item which has a router link, while not letting the other views to go away.
But all I see is that the ***right-panel.component*** loading and the not the ***edit-details.component*** which is the child of it. I do that have the `<router-outlet>` tag in the right-panel html page.

**PS:** I have added the modules in their respective module to imports array. let me know if I should provide more details or page to help solve this.

See below link for folder structure.

[image]

Also this is what my ***right-module.ts*** looks like

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {EditDetailsComponent} from './edit-details/edit-details.component';
import {RightPanelRoutingModule} from './right-panel-routing.module';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RightPanelRoutingModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    EditDetailsComponent
  ]
})
export class RightPanelModule { }
```

The HTML page that has router Link

```
  <div class="pat-list">
    <mat-selection-list [multiple]="false">
      <mat-list-option *ngFor="let pat of patients" [value]="pat.patient_id" [routerLink]="['editDetails', pat.patient_id]" (click)="details(pat)">
        <mat-icon mat-list-icon><img src="{{ pat.photo ? pat.photo : pat.gender == 'male' ? 'assets/images/personIcon.png' : 'assets/images/personIcon.png'}}" style="font-size: 20px;width: 50px; height: 50px;" /></mat-icon>
        <div class="pat-text">
          <div mat-line class="pat-name">{{pat.name}}</div>
          <mat-icon matSuffix>keyboard_arrow_right</mat-icon>
        </div>
        <mat-divider></mat-divider>
      </mat-list-option>
    </mat-selection-list>
  </div>
```

Adding sample in to public git hub repo.
https://github.com/JudahIrani/test

Comment: Your app-routing module imports right-panel module, not right-panel-routing module. You haven't shared the code for right-panel, only right-panel-routing.

Comment: Hey @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, thanks for responding. I have edited my question and added link to project structure also.

Comment: Could you show how that `routerLink` looks like? Or even better, could you create a StackBlitz ?

Comment: Hey @AndreiGătej, added the html page to the question.

Comment: Is that the HTML of `RightPanelComponent`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the fix, turns out there was `<router-outlet>` directive missing for the mid panel that would eventually show the right panel. Sorry guys, told you I was new to this! A simplest mistake made me waste 2 days thinking about it.

Answer (score 0):

in angular many ways to define child routine , but for solution you can use like this :
**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
  path: 'patients',
  loadChildren: './main-page/main/patients/right-panel/right-panel.module#RightPanelModule'
  }
];
// if you need "Data" property you can use
```

**right-panel-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
  path: 'editDetails/:id',
  component: EditDetailsComponent,
  pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```

this is work for you.

Comment: I got error saying that can't find module, unless I do it this way the module isn't recognized.

`loadChildren: () => import('./main/right-panel/right-panel.module').then(m => m.RightPanelModule)`

Comment: To help better I am following this 

[link] (https://stackblitz.com/angular/glnrqmrgypy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcrisis-center%2Fcrisis-center-routing.module.ts)

Comment: can you import **right-panel.module.ts** in  **app.module.ts**  ???

Comment: I am adding in a git hub link to the question,since I cannot buy stackblitz to put my code.